# Expo ejected react native project uploaded apk (build by android studio) has more permissions than in manifest file

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, permissions, expo

I have react native project which recently ejected by expo (bare workflow). This is my `AndroidManifest.xml` .

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="example.package">
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="https://exp.host/example" />
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="41.0.0" />
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS" android:value="0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_RELEASE_CHANNEL" android:value="default" />

  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:screenOrientation="unspecified">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="example"/>
        <data android:scheme="example.package"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity" android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

As you can see there are only 6 permissions have been mentioned.

But after I created `app bundle` for this project using `android studio` and uploaded it to google play console, There are 29 permission are showing as required.

[image]

What is the reason for this behaviour ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could have libs that add permissions in their manifest, when you compile the project your manifest gets merged with libraries manifests.

Open your manifest in Android Studio then at the bottom there should be a Merged Manifest view

Comment: Yes. I can see other permissions in merged manifest view. I did remove and now those permissions were added to manifest file with `tools:node="remove"` tag. I'm new to android studio. Is this the correct way to remove the permissions ?

Comment: Not really, the libs that add permissions probably does so for a reason.
So you should look at what lib adds permissions you don't want to have and replace/remove the libs if you don't use them. Just removing the manifest permission for them have a big chance of breaking their functionality.